# Java Swing option dialog modifications

Tags: java, swing

I use the code below to create an option dialog.

How would i add space between the "Confirm" and "Cancel" button.

I want to remove the question mark, but i can't center the text when i change the dialog to a JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE.

```
String[] options = { "Confirm", "Cancel" };
int selected = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
               parent, "Confirm Trade","Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
               JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
```

Comment: You have to construct your own JDialog if you want to change the appearance of a JOptionPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others have said, I think you'd have create a custom JDialog to get everything you want, but if you just wanted centered text, this should work:

```
String[] options = { "Confirm", "Cancel" };
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new JLabel("Confirm Trade"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
int selected = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
               frame, panel,"Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
               JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
```

I know it doesn't solve everything, but I figured I'd leave it here in case it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe its possible or at least easy to modify that. It would be much easier just to create a new JFrame and add whatever you want to it

Comment: Consider a modal JDialog rather than a JFrame

Comment: that's kind of what i thought, but figured i'd check